# proper way to access json data in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsonparser

I'm trying to access data in a json file but not completely sure how to.  I'm trying to access the "animation_file" in this json:

```
 "items": [{
                    "newUser": {
                    "steps": [
                              {
                              "id": 0,
                              "step_title": "stepConcept",
                              "visible": false,
                              "animation_file": "Welcome_Step_01_V01"
                              },
                              {
                              "id": 1,
                              "step_title": "stepSafety",
                              "visible": true,
                              "animation_file": "Welcome_Step_02_V01"
                              },
                              {
                              "id": 2,
                              "step_title": "stepFacilitator",
                              "visible": true,
                              "animation_file": "Welcome_Step_03_V01"
                              },
                              {
                              "id": 3,
                              "step_title": "stepTransparency",
                              "visible": true,
                              "animation_file": "Welcome_Step_04_V01"
                              }
                              ]
                    },
```

This is what I have so far:

```
 guard let items = welcomeJSON["items"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}

        for item in items {
            if (isNewUser) {
                if let newUser = item["newUser"] as? [String:Any] {
                    if let steps = newUser["steps"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                        for embeddedDict in steps {
                            for (key, value) in embeddedDict {
                                if let val = value as? Bool, val == true {
                                    print(key)
                                    newUserViews.append(key)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        listOfViews = newUserViews
                        listOfViews = [STEP_CONCEPT, STEP_SAFETY, STEP_FACILITATOR, STEP_TRANSPARENCY]
                        maxPages = listOfViews.count
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
```

Does this seem correct?  I feel like I may be missing a step.

Comment: You have to get the value for key `animation_file` it's the same way as getting the value for key `newUser` or `steps`. And why do you enumerate the dictionary instead of getting the value for key `visible` directly?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to get the value of "animation_file" only if the value of visible is true and you want to put it in newUserViews array. The code below should help you with it :

```
guard let items = welcomeJSON["items"] as? [[String:Any]] else {return}

    for item in items {
        if (isNewUser) {
            if let newUser = item["newUser"] as? [String:Any] {
                if let steps = newUser["steps"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    for embeddedDict in steps {
                        if let visible = newUser["visible"] as? Bool, visible == true, let animationFile = newUser["animation_file"] as? String  {
                            newUserViews.append(animationFile)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    listOfViews = newUserViews
                    listOfViews = [STEP_CONCEPT, STEP_SAFETY, STEP_FACILITATOR, STEP_TRANSPARENCY]
                    maxPages = listOfViews.count
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Rest of your code doesn't seems to be correct in my mind but the code above should resolve your current issue.